# how to modify the pose of a robot by msgs?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The name of a existing model is "ball". I use "this->node->Advertisemsgs::Pose(std::string("~/") + ball + "/pose");" to create a transport::PublisherPtr, but it doesn't work. How to create a publisherPtr?
thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5225/how-to-modify-the-pose-of-a-robot-by-msgs?/) by [Sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/476/sam/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115/isura/) on 2014-01-16**:
Can you provide more information about how it fails? Does it fail to compile? Seg fault or the message is not published? Please also include a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A model does not automatically create a topic through which you can modify it's pose.

There is a general purpose topic called `~/model/modify` which receives a [model message](http://gazebosim.org/msgs/2.0.0/model_8proto.html)

You can use the topic and message like this:

```
transport::PublisherPtr modelPub = this->node->Advertise<msgs::Model>("~/model/modify");
msgs::Model msg;
msg.set_name("ball");
msgs::Set(msg.mutable_pose(), math::Pose(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
modelPub->Publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/476/sam/) on 2014-01-16**:
thanks a lot!

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-09-10**:
I am trying to do the same thing but I'm having some issues.
I started from the following example (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e18491b2ff1a/examples/stand_alone/publisher/?at=default) and modified it to use the above code. The result is that the model jumps around in Gazebo, always returning to it's original position, in a very discontinuous way. You can see my code here: http://pastebin.com/BG1HLhDn

What is the problem?

**Comment by [FH](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21627/fh/) on 2020-03-20**:
Hi,
When I trying to copy your code to run in Gazebo7. I got the following error:
'error: no matching function for call to ‘Set(gazebo::msgs::Pose*, gazebo::math::Pose&)’
Seem like a conversion problem.
Thank in advance.